# fopen error, null property

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write to a file from javacript in an aspx page and i get an error. Here is my code and the error.

```
   var fh = fopen("c:\temp\MyFile.txt", 3); // Open the file for writing

               if (fh != -1) // If the file has been successfully opened
               {

                   fwrite(fh, saveData); // Write the string to a file
                   fclose(fh); // Close the file 
               }
```

The value of the property 'fopen' is null or undefined, not a Function object.

Any help?

Comment: Does fopen exist in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

fopen is not a JavaScript function.